# Descending sequence for module with finite length

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring and $M$ be a finite $R$-module with finite length. Then the descending sequence
$$M\supseteq\mathfrak{m}M\supseteq\mathfrak{m}^2M\supseteq\cdots\supseteq\mathfrak{m}^nM\supseteq\cdots$$
must stable for $n$ big enough. My question is will it always descend to zero? Maybe this is very simple but I just can't see it. Hope someone would help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the Krull intersection theorem?

Comment: @metalspringpro Thanks, I just forgot that. So the finite length condition is unnecessary?

Comment: The chain will not stabilize unless $M$ has finite length, though the intersection is still $0$.

Comment: If $m^{k+1}M=m^kM$ then $m^kM=0$ by Nakayama.